# Swift setting values to empty optional yields failure

Tags: swift, crash, option-type

I have a data class called `DataManager` and this is what it looks like:

```
class DataManager: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var money: Double = 0
    var netWorth: Double = 0
    var businessNum: Int = 0
    var generalEPM: Int = 0
    var generalThreat: Int = 0


    override init() {

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.money = (aDecoder.decodeDouble(forKey: "DMMoney"))
        self.netWorth = (aDecoder.decodeDouble(forKey: "DMNetWorth"))
        self.businessNum = (aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "DMBusinessNum"))
        self.generalEPM = (aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "DMGeneralEPM"))
        self.generalThreat = (aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "DMGeneralThreat"))
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(self.money, forKey: "DMMoney")
        aCoder.encode(self.netWorth, forKey: "DMNetWorth")
        aCoder.encode(self.businessNum, forKey: "DMBusinessNum")
        aCoder.encode(self.generalEPM, forKey: "DMGeneralEPM")
        aCoder.encode(self.generalThreat, forKey: "DMGeneralThreat")
    }

}
```

I then create an optional instance of this class since it can be empty (once a user opens the app for the first time):

```
var appData:DataManager?
```

I then have 2 functions to save and load the data:

```
func saveData() {
    appData?.transformNetWorth()
    appData?.updateAllVariables()
    let encodeData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: appData)
    userDefaults.set(encodeData, forKey: "appData")
    userDefaults.synchronize()
}

func loadData() {

    if let x = userDefaults.object(forKey: "appData") as? Data {
        appData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: x) as? DataManager
    }
}
```

In my AppDelegate, as soon as the app runs it checks if `DataManager` is empty, and if it is, it gives it the following values:

```
if appData == nil {
    appData?.money = 100
    appData?.businessNum = 0
    appData?.generalThreat = 0
    appData?.generalEPM = 0
    appData?.netWorth = 0
    saveData()
}
```

Nevertheless, after this occurs and after the saveData() function is called, I try using appData!.money, but the application crashes telling me: "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping...", although I gave values to all of the class parameters. Please help because I have no idea of where the mistake is. Thanks!

(Of course loadData() is called before trying to access data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`appData` is `nil`. You never assign it a value.

You want something like:

```
if appData == nil {
    appData = DataManager()
    appData?.money = 100
    // and the rest
}
```

That fixes the immediate issue but you really need to refactor all of your code to work with optionals more cleanly.

For example, update your `saveData` to:

```
func saveData() {
    if let appData = appData {
        appData.transformNetWorth()
        appData.updateAllVariables()
        let encodeData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: appData)
        userDefaults.set(encodeData, forKey: "appData")
    }
}
```

This avoids all of the needless use of `?` and it ensures you don't run all of the code if `appData` is `nil`.